# How to count attributes from an arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have an arrayList

```
 Dog spot = new Dog("Spot", "Lab","Blonde", Tail.OTTER,"Yes", 50, 3);
 Dog buddy = new Dog("Buddy", "Pit Bull", "Black", Tail.DOCKED,"Yes", 60, 2);
 Dog mia = new Dog ("Mia", "Pug", "Brown", Tail.RING ,"No", 70, 4);
```

Now the 50,60,and 70 are the weight of the dogs. I'd like to total them up without writing out  lengthy, non flexible code such like:

```
int totalWeight = spot.weight + buddy.weight + mia.weight;
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int totalWeight = 0;
for (final Dog dog : dogs) {
    totalWeight += dog.getWeight();
}
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind helping a little more how would I make it so it would only add together the dogs over 55 pounds?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out on my own. Thank you, for the fast help!

Answer (score 2):

Place every object in a list

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
dogs.add(spot);
dogs.add(buddy);
dogs.add(mia);

int result = 0;
for(Dog dog : dogs) {
 result += dog.getWeight(); 
}
```